# Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Tags: maven, jar, сборка

Подскажите, собирал проект maven clocks.jar через intellij idea
сборка прошла успешно, а вот при запуске выдает ошибку

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

вот pom.xml, почему он не может его найти?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>home</groupId>
    <artifactId>Clocks</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jar-resource-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>E:\IT\GitHub\Clocks\src\main\java\Main.java</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathLayoutType>simple</classpathLayoutType>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <mode>development</mode>
                            <url>${project.url}</url>
                            <key>value</key>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: У вас точно есть класс с точкой входа в программу - public static void main(String args[]) {}?

Comment: есть, и класс называется Main и метод в нем есть public static void main(String args[]) {}